# Can I use a style.php?

Tags: theming

I was wondering if I can change the style sheet of a theme from style.css to style.php and Drupal will use it? I tried it and it didn't work. 
I did, of course, change the file name in template.php as well. Is there anything else I need to consider?

Comment: What do you pretend to do by using php in a stylesheet? May be there is a better way,

Comment: i want to use variables for the colors so I don't miss any when changing them.

Comment: I think your aproach is not the best one, I'll suggest you asolution and we can discuss the pros and cons.

Comment: If you want to use variables in CSS, have a look at SCSS (or SASS, whichever you prefer): http://sass-lang.com/ it allows variables, selector nesting, and a whole bunch of other nice things. You can compile them into CSS files with a ruby gem or use [this module](https://www.drupal.org/project/sass)

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can but you shouldn't.

When adding a stylesheet, Drupal does not tamper the file names. So regardless of the way you add it, your PHP file or whatever file name you use will be added to the `import` clauses or to the `link` tag.

However, note that Drupal can combine those CSS files, and it uses `file_get_contents()` function to get the file contents. In that case, Drupal will get the source code of your PHP file, making this approach fail.

If you want to add dynamic CSS, you can go for some workarounds though.

- Add all possible styles to one stylesheet under different classes, and only change the class name of the HTML that you want to change styles of.
- Have a predefined set of stylesheets, and only add the ad-hoc in a preprocess function or something.
- Add the styles as inline CSS.

Other than that, the core Color module has some similar approaches that you might find useful.

Comment: Thanks for you ideas. However they involve a lot of html editing. So I guess it's less work to change the colors manually within the css. But that's okay. It's not like I "need" it, I just wanted to save some time with the dynamic css.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use variables for the colors you can, for example:

- Put the colors in a style attribute (not in the stylesheet) so you
  can change it when you want
- Define different colors for different classes and change the
  classes of the dom elements for which you want to change the color.
- Programattically edit the css file content with something like:

  $file = fopen($destination, "w+");
  fputs($file, $data);
  fclose($file);

(I wouldn't suggest this if It's something that must be done periodically).

Sure there are other ways to accomplish what you want to do without calling a php file as an stylesheet (which, for what I know, is not feasible).

Comment: Thanks for you ideas. As I also commented above, your ideas involve a lot of html editing. So I guess it's less work to change the colors manually within the css. But that's okay. It's not like I "need" it, I just wanted to save some time with the dynamic css.

Answer (score 0):

I did create a dynamic stylesheet once, as a test, by defining a menu callback at `/some/path/stylesheet.css` and returning CSS code. However it's really not a good idea because the stylesheet must be generated (or if you make a bit smarter: retrieved from cache) every time by a fully bootstrapped Drupal, which is much slower than letting the web server return the contents of a plain text file.

If you really need a dynamically generated CSS file, I would generate it when the settings change (probably triggered by a form submit), write the CSS file to the public files directory, and include the CSS file using the `#attached` property on a render array or [drupal_add_css](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_css/7.x). If I'm not mistaken, this approach is more or less what [color.module](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!color!color.module/7.x) does too.